# A solution for linux service failover

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I am looking for a solution that monitors a service on a server and runs a custom script when a problem is found.

To be more specific:
We have a service that relies on many Elastic IPs at EC2, when a problem occurs on the primary server, all those EIPs are required to move to a slave server.

I have written the script for the EIP failover, but my company wants to use an open source tool for the monitoring part.

I have looked into pacemaker/heartbeat solution but it seems too complex for what i want to achieve.

Please help me find a good solution for this problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using Nagios for monitoring?  It's open source and very configurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is as simple as watching a process and trigger scripts, monit will be your best friend:

http://mmonit.com/monit/

The good thing about monit is that it scales well if you have a lot of servers as it runs and executes everything locally on the machine being monitored.

Comment: Thank you! this seems to be the best solution for me now!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Scout](https://scoutapp.com) ?  It allows you to write your custom scripts that get executed after triggers. For example you can setup a trigger from a third server that when it can't reach one of your EIPs then it's time to do the EIP switchover.

We are currently monitoring all of our servers using Scout and are pretty happy.